# IE can't find any element on the page

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I just didn't want someone else to search for same. So, decided to write as a question here.Hope it will help other automation QAs.

All tests run successfully, until one happy day.

Then Internet Explorer was only able to navigate to some url. If I tried to getSource of page, all the html was there, but Selenium couldn't find any element.

*Chrome, Firefox and Safari work stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to remove update [#KB3008923](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3008923).

My colleague had same problem, but she couldn't see this update in the list to remove(when it was in history list), but after an hour it appeared. It just appears and disappears in Windows Updates list.

And... get auto update of browser turned off. Keep 'fixed' version for at least week or two. Then after trying if update tests work correctly you will definitely know if  that was an update who broke everything down.

Comment: Do you have a test case that passes before KB3008923, but fails afterwards? I'd be happy to escalate this if necessary.